# Select date range into different column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

| Name | Date | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2023 | 100 |
| A | 01-01-2023 | 200 |
| A | 03-01-2023 | 300 |
| B | 02-01-2023 | 400 |
| B | 03-01-2023 | 100 |
| B | 03-01-2023 | 100 |

i have this table and i want to seperate it into multiple column of date and SUM the score on that date using Query Builder laravel or Raw SQL so it become like :

| Name | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 300 | 0 | 300 |
| B | 0 | 400 | 200 |

all of this is upto the current month so january until 31 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't providing anything like your attempted query, how you are passing the date ( it is a range, month only etc ), and your desired json ouput.

its hard to even assume how you are going to do things specially you are passing a column value as column name in your desired result (which doesn't make much sense with raw sql query unless those columns
aren't dynamic).

but to give you a starting point, you can simply group them by name, then date, then do another grouping by date in the collection

e.i;

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')->select([
    'name',
    'date',
])
->selectRaw('sum(score) AS score')
->groupBy(['name', 'date'])->get();

return $result->groupBy('date');
```

then you should be able to get result in a format like below;

```
{
    "01-01-2023" : [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "date": "01-01-2023",
            "score": "300"
        }
    ],
    "02-01-2023" : [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "date": "02-01-2023",
            "score": "300"
        }
        {
            "name": "B",
            "date": "02-01-2023",
            "score": "200"
        }
    ],
    "03-01-2023" : [
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

For you desired table result, thats better be changed to a dynamic rows instead of dynamic column

**EDIT**

In reference with Karl answer, you can loop through a date range and inject additional select statement.

e.i. current month dates

```
$dateRange = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth() )->toArray();

$result = DB::table('table_name')->select(['name']);

foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $dateFormat = $date->format('d-m-Y');
    $day = $date->format('j');
    $result->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '$dateFormat' THEN Score ELSE 0 END) AS 'Day $day'");
}

return $result->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah iam using range of date to get the result, i can make it as dynamic row but its so hard to transpose that row into column

Comment: Whats the best way to achieve dynamic column in laravel ?

Comment: since you are passing a date range, then have a row for each date, I dont know how many name values each date can have but you can make the name as the columns and date as row because datets are dynamic based on your date range

Comment: there are number ways to achive it like collection mapping or looping through each item and reformat the whole result, you have to FIRST figure out what your JSON ouput should look like that matches with your desired table

Answer (score 0):

just to keep date in group by
->groupBy('date');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).